# Update of table not happening on datatype 'Text'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update SubCategoryMaster 
set SubCategoryDescription='SHARPENERANDRULER' 
where SubCategoryDescription='SharpenerAndRuler'
```

In this query, `SubCategoryDescription`'s datatype is `TEXT`. When I execute this query, I get an error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Please suggest

Comment: `WHERE CAST(SubCategoryDescription AS VARCHAR(4000))='SharpenerAndRuler'` ?

Answer (score 0):

[blog.sqlauthority.com](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-fix-error-402-the-data-types-ntext-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator/) has an answer for you. The following is the relevant part of the blog post, in case this link is dead:

**Solution 1**: Convert the data types to match with each other using CONVERT function.

Change the datatype of the MyText to nvarchar.

```
SELECT ID, MyText
FROM TestTable
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MyText) = N'AnyText'
GO
```

**Solution 2**: Convert the data type of columns from NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX) (TEXT to VARCHAR(MAX)

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable
ALTER COLUMN MyText NVARCHAR(MAX)
GO
```

Now you can run the original query again and it will work fine.

**Solution 3**: Using LIKE command instead of Equal to command.

```
SELECT ID, MyText
FROM TestTable
WHERE MyText LIKE 'AnyText'
GO
```